# Print only jasmine focused tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

It is difficult to describe how useful and convenient the ["Focused Specs"](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) feature of jasmine >=2.1 is. By using `fdescribe` and/or `fit` we can run only the specified tests without modifying the protractor config.

The only problem is the output on the console. *It prints out every single spec matching the pattern in the protractor configuration*.

First, the focused specs test results are printed. This information is useful:

```
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
open Case Screen
  should display correct url ...
 Passed
.  should display summary description ... 
 Passed
```

Then, there is a huge output containing "Disabled" tests (~20 seconds to scroll down):

```
click the Back button after switching environment
  should redirect to Queue in previous environment ...
 Disabled
1 of 1 passed (0 skipped, 1 disabled).
...
'You have been logged out.' alert message
  should show a alert message after closing all sessions in another browser window ...
 Disabled
1 of 1 passed (0 skipped, 1 disabled).
SUCCESS: 202 specs, 0 failures, 0 skipped, 199 disabled in 12.89s.
```

In other words, there were only 3 specs out of 202 executed, but all 202 were printed on the console, 199 of them were disabled.

Is there a way to avoid having disabled specs being written on the console while having the verbose information about focused tests?

---

Note that we are using `TerminalReporter` from [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters):

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TerminalReporter({
    verbosity: 3,
    color: true,
    showStack: true
}));
```

Setting the `verbosity` to < 3 helps to solve the problem with disabled tests, but in this case, we are not getting any information about which  tests were focused:

```
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
...SUCCESS: 202 specs, 0 failures, 0 skipped, 199 disabled in 12.225s.

202 specs, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the same problem in the future - decided to use a different terminal reporter instead - [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) - it is quite configurable and provides a more precise and better formatted output (see these awesome checkboxes, for example):

[image]

Note that it still reports maximum information about the executed tests. Exactly what we needed in this case.